# Z button does not show Toggle Overlay

Tags: 3d-view, interface

In tutorial I am following, the guy is pressing  <kbd>Z</kbd> button and he has toggle overlays on top but it seems to be missing when I try to do the same.

How to do the same in my Blender or what am I doing wrong?

I'm trying to learn by replicating the workflow and constantly get stuck in first minute of the guide.

Guide:

[image: Toggle overlay available in the guide]

and my screen below that doesn't show:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable <kbd>Extra Shading Pie Menu Items</kbd> under the <kbd>Edit</kbd> > <kbd>Preferences</kbd> > <kbd>Keymap</kbd> tab

[image]